# Number keys switching applications (Ubuntu 21.10)

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 21.10

When I'm pressing the number keys above the keyboard it keeps switching applications and when I press it with the Super key the number keys are working. I think the keybindings are reversed. I did try dconf-editor but the keybindings are showing correctly. How to reverse it to default settings?

Update: In the login window, numbers are working as expected.

Comment: Sound like a hardware problem with the keyboard to me

Comment: Can we disable the switch application shortcut? (Super + 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow this setting was triggered from dash to panel gnome extension. Just turn it off

[image: Dash to panel]

Answer (score 0):

In XFCE this setting is referred to as "Mouse Emulation" and is located under Settings>Accessibility>Mouse

Deselect it and normal function of numpad should be restored.