# Ubuntu 22.04 "Jammy Jellyfish" - Numeric Keypad not working - selecting apps on taskbar

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-gnome, numpad

### Problem Summary

Numeric Keypad settings all seem to be correct when examining Ubuntu Settings > Keyboard, GNOME Tweaks > Keyboard > Additional Options, and when running from an alternate TTY session (e.g. Ctrl + Alt + F3 -> tty3).

###### Edit (04/07/2022 17:33 UTC-4)

- explain uniqueness from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372500/number-keys-switching-applications-ubuntu-21-10/1400865#1400865)

> my question applies to Ubuntu 22.04 (I've edited my Title to reflect this)
>
> while the linked answer above is similar to my issue, my symptoms differ in that numbers on my numeric keypad don't work unless I'm holding the `Shift` key, not the `Super` key.
>
> It's also worth noting that answer provided here is very detailed while the answer from [Number keys switching applications (Ubuntu 21.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372500/number-keys-switching-applications-ubuntu-21-10/1400865#1400865) isn't clear on exactly which setting needs to be changed and the provided screenshot is ambiguous in that it doesn't identify what setting was incorrect or what change was applied.

### Problem Details

Every setting appears to be correct; yet I still experience a loss of keyboard control when I hit the number 1 on the numeric keypad of my keyboard. The behavior appears to be that I'm selecting applications that are open and that have icons on my taskbar. However, I get stuck and am unable to type into any application that I select. Usually a lot of semi-random key-pressing frees up my keyboard and allows me to start using it normally again.

I noticed that the apps on my taskbar would become annotated with numbers 1-9 when I pressed one of the number keys on my keypad. Like in the image below
[number annotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVsqZ.png)

### Attempted Fixes

- I've reset everything to defaults multiple times
- Logged out, logged back in
- Rebooted multiple times
- examined org.gnome.desktop.input-sources.xkb-options using `dconf-editor`
- examined outputs of `xev`, `showkey`, and the virtual keyboard from GNOME settings

### Settings

[dconf-editor: xkb-options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Tuf.png)

[GNOME Settings > Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT3JV.png)

[Virtual Keyboard Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAMKm.png)

[GNOME Tweaks > Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FfyD.png)

[GNOME Tweaks > Keyboard > Additional Layout Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF1PT.png)

Comment: There's no need to put "Answered" in the title, just marking your answer as a solution is enough. That it has an answer will be shown in the general stream of questions, so there will be no confusion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number keys switching applications (Ubuntu 21.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372500/number-keys-switching-applications-ubuntu-21-10)

Comment: It pushed me in the right direction but it didn't specifically describe the steps to correct the issue. I was going to call-out or reference that answer as helpful but ultimately my post describes in detail the issue and steps to fix.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found this after pulling my hair out for over a week checking and rechecking xkb-layout settings in `dconf-editor`, `showkey`, `xev`, etc. etc. etc.

The *`Use hotkeys to activate apps`* setting was enabled in my Dash2Panel configuration settings. Once I disabled that setting, my numeric keypad began working normally.

[incorrect setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn2fZ.png)

[correct setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyzvv.png)

- **note:** my `Dash2Panel` settings were accessed by right-clicking on my panel / taskbar and choosing `Dash to Panel Settings`
- **special thanks to this post for helping me toward this solution**
  [Number keys switching applications (Ubuntu 21.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372500/number-keys-switching-applications-ubuntu-21-10/1400865#1400865)

Comment: This must be a bug with the extension! Super+Number should switch, but it seems here that one or another way "Super" gets "locked".

Comment: @vanadium, are you suggesting that this is a bug with the `Dash to Panel` application? If so, and you're sure, I'll happily submit a bug report to the development team.

Comment: This is erroneous behaviour, so it can be a bug with the current extension, but it could also be another problem on your system, configuration (other extensions that interfere?) or other issue with your system.

Comment: I see what you mean, and after reviewing that setting more, I tend to agree with your assessment. The setting is supposed to require `Super`, `Shift`, or `Ctrl` to be pressed along with the numeric keypad numbers or top row numbers. In my case, the hotkeys were activating without any of the modifying keys being pressed, only the number keys. I'll do some more testing and submit a bug report if it seems appropriate.